# Node.js App - Performing tasks after x number of minutes - is the queue guaranteed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have a basic node.js app that runs after x number of minutes and performs some check, like so:

```
(async () => {
    setInterval(async function () {
        for (const work of toCheck) {
            await doSomething(work)
        }
    }, the_interval);
})();
```

However I now need to scale this up however not sure on the best design pattern to help we achieve this:

- I'd like to have multiple intervals defined. I guess I could just repeat that code block:

```
let intOne = setInterval(async function () {
   // some tasks
}, the_interval_one);

let intTwo = setInterval(async function () {
   // some tasks
}, the_interval_two);
```

However is there some other approach I should look into?

- Secondly, say my first interval was 1 minute, however there were many tasks (say I have to make a DB call then process something) during which those first round of tasks aren't completed in the space of 1 minute. When the second interval loop comes around, would the new tasks be queued or is there a risk of tasks not being completed?

Also for my second interval block say 30 minute, would again things just be continue to added to one queue?
Or is this something I need to be aware of with Node.js working?

Any help guidance appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If node doesnt queue up things as mentioned above, do I need to use some library like https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull or https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue

Comment: why cant promisify db call ?